# what is the need for importing libraries multiple times

Tags: java, compiler-construction, import, package

in most code examples I see people doing this.

```
import javax.swing.*; // for the frame
import java.awt.*; // for the checkBox and the label
import java.awt.event.*; // for the checkBox listener
```

If I am correct when we say import java.awt.* it imports everything inside it, so there wont be a need to say import java.awt.event.*; or is there a speed improvement? can anyone also explain what importing a library does, is it importing a simple text class to be included in the source or telling jvm to include the byte code of whatever is imported? so importing in java does nothing but switch the namespace, so I dont have to type long class names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget the term <strike>**subpackage**</strike>. Do it quick. It does not exist in java world.

`java.awt` is a package (namespace), `java.awt.event` is another one and they have nothing in common. Their names share some characters, but the packages are totally unrelated. The import statements imports a class or some classes from exactly one package (namespace). If you need classes from a different package (namespace), then you have to add another import statement.

---

*BTW*, in response to a comment to another answer: You do not have to use import statements. If you don't use them, you simply have to use the fully qualified classnames in your java source file (except: classes from `java.lang` and the current package are imported automatically). So `import` could be considered as a convenient way to keep the code readable.

Importing *is not* required in order to use a class in your source file.

Comment: so importing in java does nothing but switch the namespace, so I dont have to type long class names?

Comment: It's not *switching* namespaces. If you do `import java.util.*;` you can write `List<Integer> list = null;`, otherwise you'd have to say `java.util.List<Integer> list = null;`. Both statements are equivalent and compile to the same byte code.

Comment: @dave it isn't *switching* namespaces. It is *opening* namespaces.

Comment: Classes from the current package are also imported automatically.

Answer (score 4):

The line...

> ```
> import java.awt.*;
> ```

...doesn't mean that all subpackages will also be imported. You have to explicitly import every package. As an example, importing java.* doesn't give you the entire java library.

For what it's worth, I recommend importing the specific classes only unless you have good reason to use *.

Comment: Please avoid the term *subpackages*. Java packages don't have any hierarchical structure.

Comment: Indeed - bad terminology. Since they are based on the filesystem I let a "subfolder" word slip in.

Comment: not correct again - the standard Classloader expects `*.class` files at a location in the the filesystem that maps to the package name. But that's just one way, other classloaders could implement different algorithms to find classfiles - consider a classloader loading class files from a database: there wouldn't be files and folders. But the package name could be the primary key in some CLASS table.

Comment: your welcome - when we learn Java we're told to store the classes according to the package name, otherwise the applications won't compile. Later we see, that this is not the full truth ;)

Answer (score 1):

Importing a package doesn't import its subpackages.

Importing is about switching the namespace, too.

If you only had `import java.awt.*` and you were to use the class `java.awt.Outer.Inner`, everywhere in your code you have to refer to it as `Outer.Inner`.

By contrast, when you say `import java.awt.Outer.*`, you can refer to the inner class as just `Inner`.

Comment: so importing in java does nothing but switch the namespace, so I dont have to type long class names?

Comment: Please avoid the term subpackages. Java packages don't have any hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 1):

Importing is just a compile time feature, in bytecode you will find only direct references to specific classes, everytime its instance is used.
"import" constructs exist just to eliminate use of full class name everytime.

Comment: Just a quick remark: please don't mix the concepts *class* and *instance*. I'd say: "*[...], everytime it's used.*".